# Google Translate not translating without refreshing the page

Tags: onclick, google-translate, page-refresh

I have installed Google Translate on my website https://news.steppingstone.org/. The anchor tags populate on URL when language is selected but the page itself does not translate unless page is refreshed. This is the code for the translate script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT}, 'google_translate_element');
    }

    function triggerHtmlEvent(element, eventName) {
      var event;
      if (document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
      } else {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.eventType = eventName;
        element.fireEvent('on' + event.eventType, event);
      }
    }

    jQuery('.lang-select').click(function() {
      var theLang = jQuery(this).attr('data-lang');
      jQuery('.goog-te-combo').val(theLang);

      //alert(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
      window.location = jQuery(this).attr('href');
      location.reload();

    });
  </script>
 <style>

/* Remove Google top bar and margin */
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
    display: none !important;
    } 
body {
    top: 0px !important; 
    }
    
/* Disable google translate original text tooltips */  
#goog-gt-tt, .goog-te-balloon-frame{display: none !important;} 
.goog-text-highlight { background: none !important; box-shadow: none !important;}
    
</style> */


<style>
```

What am I missing? Should there be a delay or a forced refresh on the page upon language selection?

I added an on click action to the <a tag but it just refreshed the page without translating. I was expecting this function to force a refresh of the page and translate the page.